# 301 redirect: add directory to url string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a website: http://www.blog.si, 
and I want to redirect all requests to root folder of domain to sub folder: http://www.blog.si/sub/.

Examples: I want the following url strings to redirect to http://www.blog.si/sub/:

```
http://www.blog.si/
http://www.blog.si/existingSite.html
http://www.blog.si/randomString
http://www.blog.si/ghdfgdgsdfg
```

But, I dont want an existing sub directories to be redirected:

```
 http://www.blog.si/existingDirectory/
```

I am guessing that the solution is simple, but I am searching for it for hours now and dont know what to search for anymore.

Comment: have a look:http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/?$ /sub/ [L,R]
```